# What are precautions you should take when you allow users to edit HTML and CSS on your website?

Tags: html, css, customization, security

Tumblr is really impressive in the sense that it allows users to customize their profiles and such. You're allowed to edit the HTML and CSS of your profile.

This is something I want to apply to my own site. However, I'm sure that this will be a big burden on security.

Does anyone have any tips or precautions for a feature like Tumblr's? Also, is it advisable to store the editable HTML and CSS in a database? Thank you :D

P.S.
What about server-side scripting? Lets say I wanted to grant the option of allowing the user to script a button that does something to the database. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a *very* difficult thing to get right, in my experience, if you want users to be able to use absolutely all of HTML/CSS. What you could do, however, is strip all CSS and HTML attributes, and only put "safe" code on a whitelist.

### Examples

```
<p>This is legal code.</p>

<p><a onload="alert('XSS!')">The attribute should be filtered out</a></p>

<p><a href="http://google.com/" class="blue">This is a legal link.</a>
Of course you should still sanitize the href attribute!</p>

<h1>This is bad, because the rest of the page is going to huge,
so make sure there's a closing tag

<style>
.blue {
    color: #00f; // keep this (by whitelist)
    strange-css-rule: possibly-dangerous; // Filter this out!
}
</style>
```

Those are just some of the pitfalls you can encounter, though.

I'm not familiar with Tumblr, but I'm pretty sure they're doing something similar to this.

As for the database question, of course you can store HTML and CSS in a database, many systems do this. In your case, you would just need one representation anyway, anything else would just confuse the user ("Why is my CSS rule not applied; it's right there in the code!")

Comment: What about server-side scripting? Lets say I wanted to grant the option of allowing the user to script a button that does something to the database. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: This strongly depends on your use case, so you should probably ask another question. Under no circumstances would I allow users to just insert custom PHP/Ruby/what-have-you code though. Far too much potential for abuse.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `php` then, for database issue you can use mini API system. For example, you want user to allow comment on something and save it in your database, then you can use API like this.

First, `api.php` file, (URL Location: `http://yoursite.com/api.php`)

```
<?php

// ID and Key can be different for all users.
// id = 1234
// key = 'secret_key'

// function = name of the function, user can call
// option = parameter passed to the function

// Now check if id, key, function and option are requested and then
// call function if it exists.

if(isset($_GET['id'], $_GET['key'], $_GET['function'], $_GET['option']) {
   $id = $_GET['id'];
   $key = $_GET['key'];

   if($id == '1234' && $key == 'secret_key') {

       // define all functions here
       function make_comment($option) {
           ...code for saving comment to database...
       }

       if(function_exists($_GET['function'])) {
           $_GET['function']($_GET['option']);
       }
   }
}

?>
```

Then uesr can call this function from any button using simple call to the API, like

`<a href='http://yoursite.com/api.php?id=1234&key=secret_key&function=make_comment&option=i_am_comment'></a>`